# Julia: Get body of a function

Tags: julia

**How can I access the body of a function?**

**Context:** I have functions inside modules which I execute with specific parameter values. I want to "keep a record" of these parameter values and corresponding functional forms. Below my attempt:

```
module MyModule

using Parameters  # Parameters provides unpack() macro
using DataFrames  # DataFrames used to store results in a DataFrame

struct ModelParameters
    γ::Float64
    U::Function
end

function ModelParameters(;
    γ = 2.0,
    U = c -> if γ == 1.0; log(c); else (c^(1-γ)-1)/(1-γ) end
    )
    ModelParameters(γ, U)
end

function show_constants(mp::ModelParameters)
    @unpack γ = mp
    d = DataFrame(
        Name = ["γ"],
        Description = ["parameter of U"],
        Value = [γ]
    )
    return(d)
end

function show_functions(mp::ModelParameters)
    @unpack U = mp
    d = DataFrame(
        Name = ["U"],
        Description = ["function with parameter γ"],
        Value = [U]
    )
    return d
end


export
ModelParameters
show_constants,
show_functions

end  # end of MyModule
```

Keeping a record:

```
using Main.MyModule
mp = ModelParameters()

MyModule.show_constants(mp)

1×3 DataFrame
 Row │ Name    Description     Value   
     │ String  String          Float64 
─────┼─────────────────────────────────
   1 │ γ       parameter of U      2.0


MyModule.show_functions(mp)

1×3 DataFrame
 Row │ Name    Description                Value 
     │ String  String                     #2#4… 
─────┼──────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ U       function with parameter γ  #2
```

This is quite useful to store scalars and arrays value, but not for functions. How could I replace `#2` with something useful?

Examples of what would be useful:

`c -> if γ == 1.0; log(c); else (c^(1-γ)-1)/(1-γ) end,`

or

`(c^(1-2.0)-1)/(1-2.0)`

or (magically simplified):

`1-c^(-1.0)`

My question is somewhat related to [Julia: show body of function (to find lost code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26223649/julia-show-body-of-function-to-find-lost-code).

Comment: FYI, [Sugar.jl](https://github.com/SimonDanisch/Sugar.jl)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve method content as an \`Expr\`ession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42514371/retrieve-method-content-as-an-expression)

Answer (score 1):

You can find a similar discussion [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/nice-way-to-display-functions/4089), the best solution for functions that fit in a single line in my opinion is something like this:

```
type mytype
    f::Function
    s::String
end

mytype(x::String) =  mytype(eval(parse(x)), x)
Base.show(io::IO, x::mytype) = print(io, x.s)
```

instead of handing over a function as an expression you give it as a String:

```
t = mytype("x -> x^2")
```

you call the function like this

```
t.f(3)
```

and access the String representation like this:

```
t.s
```

Comment: Would you update your answer to make it work with Julia 1.0+, please. Thanks!